# c++ vector of vectors size of the next column

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, detection, template-matching

I am writing a code to do some template matching using cv::matchTemplate but I have run into some problems with the 2-dimensional vector of vectors (vov) I created which I have called vvABC. At the moment, my vov has 10 elements which can change based on the values I pass while running the code.

My problem is moving from one column in my vov to the next so I can calculate the size. From my understanding of how vov works, if I have my elements stored in my vov as:

```
C_A  C_B
 0    0
 1    1
 2    2
      3
      4
      5
      6
```

To calculate the size of the first column, I should simply do something like:
vvABC[0].size() to get the size of the first column (which would give 3 in this case) and vvABC[1].size() to get the size of the second column (which would give 7). The problem I am now faced with is both of them give '3' in both cases which is obviously wrong.

Can someone please help me out on how I can get the correct size of the next column?

I stored my detections in my vvABC, now I want to match them one at a time.

Comment: Nice explanation, but you might get better answers if you show some code -- specifically how you create and populate vvABC.

Comment: @Markku: I have posted the code...with comments, I hope it's easy to understand...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you made a mistake here:

```
for (uint iCaTemplate = iCa + 1; iCaTemplate < vvABC[iCa].size(); ++iCaTemplate) {
```

`iCa` is an index on the 'first level' of vector (**of size 2 in your example above**), i.e. columns, and you use it to go through the elements of the 'second level' of vector, i.e. rows.

Comment: @ JGab Okay, So it works like: [columns][rows]? So how do I go to the next column so I can get its size? Because I need to iterate over all the detections there too

Comment: @ JGab...But if it is vv[columns][row] then it should still work because vv[0][0] will be the 1st element in column 0. Then vv[1][0] will be the first element of column 1...assuming the numbering starts from 0. So vvABC[iCaTemplate].size() should return the size of the 1st column right? This is what I thought but it hasn't turned out so...do you have any idea of how I can get the size of the elements in the 1st column? This is all I need to get the code to work properly.

Comment: How it works is irrelevent, you can think of it however you like (rows, communs or the inverse). And yes you are correct vvABC[iCaTemplate].size() will return the size of the first column IF iCaTemplate==0. What i pointed out is that you are mixing column and row indexes in the statement that i highlited.

Comment: @ JGab...thanks for all your help...I finally found out what the problem was, I made a mistake in an earlier portion of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot guys, esp. JGab, after several debug outputs, I finally found that my vector of vectors wasn't being filled up the way I thought it was...thanks once more and my apologies for my belated response.

Comment: No problem, glad you could find the mistake!